# Reading every row in GridView on a Button Press

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a DataGrid which is created dynamically each time a user selects and item in another datagrid. I am missing one final step which has given me a 8 hour long headache. I need to read every row when a Button is pressed. Basically User press BUTTON and the program should read a value of each row (productID or Name[unique in this case]), assign a "1" value to it, insert into the database the information, and repeat the process with each row. I got until  here:

```
Protected Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcesss.Click
    For Each GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows

        'EmptySpace
    Next
End Sub
```

And that's it. I know I have the loop correctly (right?) but I don't know what to add since I can't use this code for example:

```
Dim findrow = e.Row.Cell(cellIndex).FindControl("ControlID")
```

Since it'd give me an error in e.Row. Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated :).

EDIT: Code for generating the columns under SelectedIndexChanged...

```
  If GridView2.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            '  dt = New DataTable()
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", GetType(System.String)))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Price", GetType(System.String)))
        Else
            dt = DirectCast(Session("DataTable"), DataTable)
        End If
```

Added the whole code...

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    .
    Dim row = GridView1.SelectedRow
    If Not row Is Nothing AndAlso IsNumeric(row.Cells(3).Text) Then
        Dim Price As Double = CDbl(row.Cells(3).Text)
        Dim Name As String = CStr(row.Cells(2).Text)



        If GridView2.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            '  dt = New DataTable()
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", GetType(System.String)))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Price", GetType(System.String)))
        Else
            dt = DirectCast(Session("DataTable"), DataTable)
        End If
        Session("DataTable") = dt

        Dim dr1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        dr1(0) = Name.ToString
        dr1(1) = CDbl(Price.ToString)
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1)
        GridView2.DataSource = dt
        GridView2.DataBind()




    End If
```

End Sub

Updated Button Handler

```
Protected Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcess.Click

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows

        Dim str As String = TryCast(row.FindControl("Name"), Label).Text
   'For testing purposes a MsgBox
        MsgBox(str)

    Next
```

Comment: I usually manually define my columns in the <asp:GridView> tag instead of setting autogeneratecolumns="True". When I do that and use the <asp:TemplateField>, I can then define my own controls. That way, I know which control to ask for my ID in the code-behind.  I see you're defining the columns for your DataTable programatically, but will those columns remain the same?  If so, can you manually define your columns in the mark-up and use the <asp:TemplateField> so you know which controls to grab in the code-behind?

Comment: I found a post where someone was using code similar to what you originally had.  Since they're not finding the control by ID, they're just using the cell position within the table.  Something like... "e.Row.Cells(0).Text".  That would be prone to breaking, though, when columns change.  The data you expect wouldn't be in the expected columns, and you might even end up with a control that didn't have a Text property.

Comment: Hey Rick! Thanks! I did try filling up the GridView beforehand with the column names but I haven't found a way that didn't blow in my face or didn't work for constantly adding the data. I'll add the whole code in the OP. The problem with e.Row.Cells(0) is that the code is executing under the ButtonPress, that code would work under the SelectedIndexChanged, but I need the data grabbed after the button is pressed. I'll post the full code!

Comment: I'll try what King Majid posted below and see if that works out. It's similar to what you posted... heck, its the same basically. I had a previous error with a e.row... and it caused me some mental pain :P!

Comment: Aaand no gooooo. I am definitely thinking making the columns in asp GridView like you suggest and giving them a value. But I don't think the code I have will work as well as it is right now; or I don't know how to make it work. The gist is that you select something from GridView1 and it shows up in GridView2. The code I have up there DataBinds the session so it doesn't disappear each time and also adds a row each time a new data is added. I don't know how I'd make it work honestly.

Comment: Where's the code that's not working?  Earlier you had a button click - is that still what's not working?  Can you post your updated version of that code?

Comment: Oh yes I just wanted to show the code that gives value to the Gridview that I need to get values off (that's confusing).  I'll post the updated Button Click handler. It's basically King Majid's one but I'll add it nevertheless. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: King Majid's answer got it working. Thanks a lot for your time Rick :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the Correct Button Event handling is :

```
Protected Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcesss.Click

    For Each row As GridViewRow In Grid1.Rows

        Dim _str As String = TryCast(row.FindControl("Control1"), Label).Text
    Next
```

//Added for the Second part of your Question:

To get the Value in the Name Column:

```
Dim _NameColumnValue = TryCast(row.Cells(0), DataControlFieldCell).Text
```

//just replace the Label  cast with the Control type that you desire

//just compiled the code and it works fine

regards

Comment: This should do what I need to do. The problem I have is the following... the DataColumn is created dynamically in code (example: `dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", GetType(System.String)))` ) so the FindControl doesn't work as it should. That's what's getting me to scratch my head =/!

Comment: Are you autogenerating your GridView columns?

Comment: Yes. It fires when SelectedIndexChanged is run. I'll update the code in the OP.

Comment: @LordRelix : you can use the row.cells[0] //Coz you know youre adding the Name Column first thing so it has the Zero Index

Comment: Lemme try that and see how it goes

Comment: Gives me an error, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. Tried this  `Dim str2 As String = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("Name"), Label).Text` yet it also gives me a NullValue. I beleive its a similar problem OR I am definitely inputting something wrongly.

Comment: King Majid, your Second Part got it working. Thanks a million!!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of e.Row in your example, used the variable in your For Each loop instead.

I updated your code slightly to use "gvr" so as not to confuse with the Type.

```
Protected Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcesss.Click
    For Each gvr as GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows

        ' (BAD CODE - SEE COMMENTS)
        Dim findrow = gvr.Cell(cellIndex).FindControl("ControlID")

        ' (CORRECTED CODE)
        Dim MyTextBox as TextBox = CType(gvr.FindControl("MyTextBox"), TextBox) 

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: first the GridViewRow doesnt have a property of Cell its called Cells , secondly where are you getting the Value of cellIndex From ?!!! you are inside a Foreach loop ?

Comment: You're right - I didn't look at the details of his line of code. I assumed it was working from elsewhere (e.g. a RowDataBound) and was showing how to reference the GridViewRow in the loop in place of the "e.Row". I should have checked his code. It woudldn't compile as I have answered.  I'll update with correct code, but leave the bad code referenced in the comments.